# What exactly is going on with this image URL

Tags: image, url

I was copying image links from google and I'm seeing more and more urls like this. What exactly is going on here and why are developers doing this? Heres a example.

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Answer (score 1):

That **is** the image, stored as a base64 encoded string.

So they're not giving you a link to the image, and are instead giving you the image data directly.

Copy and paste everything after the first comma into e.g. https://www.base64decode.org/ and you'll see the picture.

[image: your picture]

[This article](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/) gives a very detailed breakdown on why someone might choose to do so.  One of the main reasons is to cut down the number of requests to your webserver. (clicking that link did not make a request to google, as you had already downloaded the data)

Answer (score 0):

this image is just encoded using base64.
why people do this ? depend on the project. This way your page will be a bit heavier, but your image will be inside the page. If you use an URL, to load your image the browser will need to make a call.

Maybe the best call to do that, is this way you don't depend on another website to save and keep your image